# how to skip an error in this code?? (Tkinter and openpyxl involved)

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

thanks for helping!

I have a spreadsheet that records my income and expenses, with dates, description, debit and credit amount. I wanted to used openpyxl to automate the process of adding values that are in a particular category, the program kind of works now, but the problem is: when I am searching for a phrase that don't exist in the sheet, the program crash, it can not do the things it suppose to before and after the search phrase that dont exist.

for example,
when i wanted to calculate the subtotal of search phrase "wage" and the put the subtotal into a target cell, it works fine. the problem comes out when i ask the program to look for something that isnt there.

I ask the program to look for wage, and create a subtotal, works fine and suppose to store the value at a defined target, when i ask the program to look for tax (which dont exist) the program showed nothing,  then i ask the program to get the subtotal of rent (which exists). The program cant make the changes.

i am relatively new to all this.... so thanks again for helping! :)

```
from tkinter import *
import openpyxl as xl

window = Tk()
window.title("Excel Automation")  # rename the title


def define_subtotal():
    file_name = str(file_name_input_field.get())  # Collects the text from the text entry box
    sheet_name = str(sheet_name_label_name_input_field.get())  # Collects the text from the text entry box
    global wb   # declare Workbook as global variable
    wb = xl.load_workbook(file_name)  # define workbook
    sheet = wb[sheet_name]  # Define sheet name
    col_num = int(search_column_input_field.get())
    search_phrase = search_phrase_input_field.get()
    offset_col = int(offset_col_input_field.get())
    target_col_num = int(target_col_input_field.get())
    target_row_num = int(target_row_input_field.get())

    total = 0
    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        cell = sheet.cell(row, col_num)
        if cell.value is None:
            continue
        else:
            if search_phrase.casefold() in str(cell.value).casefold():
                total += cell.offset(column=offset_col).value
                total_description = sheet.cell(target_row_num, target_col_num + 1)
                total_description.value = "Subtotal of : " + search_phrase
                total_cell = sheet.cell(target_row_num, target_col_num)
                total_cell.value = total
                output.delete(0.0, END)
                output.insert(END, "Subtotal for " + search_phrase + " defined")
            else:
                continue


def execute():
    output.delete(0.0, END)  # clear the text box
    new_file_name = new_file_input_field.get()
    output.insert(END, "Calculations complete!")
    wb.save(new_file_name + ".xlsx")


def import_excel_file():
    output.delete(0.0, END)  # clear the text box
    output.insert(END, "File imported")
    sheet_name_label_name_input_field.config (state='disabled')
    import_button.config (state='disabled')
    file_name_input_field.config (state='disabled')


def close_window():  # exit function
    window.destroy()
    exit()


### CONTENTS

file_name_label = Label(window, text="File Name:")
file_name_input_field = Entry(window, width=38, borderwidth=2)
sheet_name_label = Label(window, text="Sheet Name:")
sheet_name_label_name_input_field = Entry(window, width=38, borderwidth=2)
import_button = Button(window, text="Import", padx=35, pady=0, command=import_excel_file)
search_phrase_label = Label(window, text="Search Phrase:")
search_phrase_input_field = Entry(window, width=38, borderwidth=2)
search_column_label = Label(window, text="Search Column:")
search_column_input_field = Entry(window, width=38, borderwidth=2)
offset_col_label = Label(window, text="Offset Column:")
offset_col_input_field = Entry(window, width=38, borderwidth=2)
target_col_label = Label(window, text="Target Column:")
target_col_input_field = Entry(window, width=38, borderwidth=2)
target_row_label = Label(window, text="Target Row:")
target_row_input_field = Entry(window, width=38, borderwidth=2)
new_file_label = Label(window, text="Name of New file:")
new_file_input_field = Entry(window, width=38, borderwidth=2)
define_subtotal_button = Button(window, text="Define Subtotal", padx=5, pady=0, command=define_subtotal)
execute_button = Button(window, text="Execute", padx=5, pady=0, command=execute)
# contents Column 2
status_label = Label(window, text="Status:")
output = Text(window, width=50, height=25, wrap=WORD, bg="white")  # wrap=WORD : wrap text when in overflow.
output.insert(END, "Drag and drop file into project file\n"
                   "Define File Name and Sheet Name\n"
                   "Example: filename.xlsx /.xlsm/ xltx/.xltm")
exit_button = Button(window, text="exit", width=14, command=close_window)

### THE GRID

file_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
file_name_input_field.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=3, sticky=W)
sheet_name_label.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
sheet_name_label_name_input_field.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=3, sticky=W)
import_button.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W, padx=5)
search_phrase_label.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
search_phrase_input_field.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
search_column_label.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
search_column_input_field.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
offset_col_label.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
offset_col_input_field.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
target_col_label.grid(row=11, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
target_col_input_field.grid(row=12, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
target_row_label.grid(row=13, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
target_row_input_field.grid(row=14, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
new_file_label.grid(row=15, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
new_file_input_field.grid(row=16, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
define_subtotal_button.grid(row=17, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5)
# GRID column 1
execute_button.grid(row=17, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5)
# GRID Column 2
status_label.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, sticky=W)
output.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=25, padx=5, sticky=NE)
exit_button.grid(row=17, column=2, sticky=E)

window.mainloop()

[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Please include the exception when your program crashes.

Comment: ok, i do agree that an exception make  the code more user friendly. but i just change the code, so the subtotal is displayed in the output box instead, is not perfect, but it serves the purpose somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be it will be a good option to use

```
try:
   your code
except:
    pass
```

And run your code inside of this from which you want to skip the error with this try except. if any exception happened then it  will ignore this and will be running.